# What is this connector in a power supply for a server?

Tags: connector

I have a server power supply that I'd like to use for a project but it has these unusual connectors on the back. What is the best connectors to use? I've also attached a photo of what it normally connects in to.

[image: psu connectors]

[image: psu inserts into]

Comment: That might be a connector from Samtec. Maybe their Powerstrip line or MPower line.

Comment: ‘Best’ is subjective. Best as in cheapest or as in suitable? The obvious solution is to use the correct connectors. To use anything else would require significant modification. You would also need to know the connections and how to make the psu operate. Note - these power supplies usually can output many Amps of current. Get things wrong and you may create a dangerous situation involving fire and burns. No joke.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for correct. I already use power spade connectors which work... But I'm looking for a connector that will provide sufficient/correct contact. This power supply puts out 12v 200amps, so yeah, lots of juice.

Comment: Almost like Samtec, but not quite I think. This is one option from Samtec though: https://www.samtec.com/products/pet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called power blades and there are several formats - number of blades each side so center data/configuration block.

Here are some examples...
http://www.alltopconnector.com/en-global/Product/products/Series/35

Comment: AllTop's connectors may look similar to OP's connectors, but they are incompatible with them. For one thing, they are of the opposite gender: OP's male connectors are shrouded, while AllTop's females are shrouded.

Answer (score 2):

That is a hybrid back-plane connector. It is also a drawer connector.
Many manufacturers make various, mutually incompatible versions.
This particular version is made by Amphenol.

That is an [Amphenol PwrBlade+](https://www.amphenol-icc.com/product-series/pwrblade-plus.html#). Specifically, [10106130-4403001LF](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-icc-fci/10106130-4403001LF/5208029) (female) and [10106124-4403001LF](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-icc-fci/10106124-4403001LF/5207951) (male).

[image] {image: digikey}

The blades are slightly different, indicating that yours are actually a knock-off or the Amphenol parts.

(By the way, I found it using my [Connector Identification Utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=standard_rect_conn&o=drawer_conn&f=pegged_drawer_conn).)

Comment: If I could I'd upvote once for the answer, and once again for the tool. I was a bit lost at first with the navigation, but once I got it, I was rather stunned. It seems all the connectors are there, and easily searchable. I'm bookmarking this. Thank you for making this available.

Comment: Thank you for the kudos!

Comment: I ended up taking it apart and finding a part number. It's a [51939-186LF](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-icc-fci/51939-186LF/5200364). So that makes it a Amphenol PwrBlade (non plus). The connector identification utility is really cool btw!

Comment: Ah! I was close. Thank you for the kudos. I hope you find it helpful in the future.